# Calling Childview Function

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch

How can I call the function `reloadData` from `ChildViewController`?

[image]

---

MainViewController.h

```
- (void)callChildFunction
{
    // Call `reloadData` from `ChildViewController`.
}
```

ChildViewController.h

```
- (void)reloadData
{
    [...]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understand your question. If you mean how can you call a method implemented in the child from the parent, you can do it like this:

```
MainViewController.m

- (void)callChildFunction
{
    [(ChildViewController *)self.childViewControllers[0] reloadData];
}
```

You'll have to import the child class into MainViewController's .m file.

Answer (score 0):

1) Setup a `protocol` and `delegate` on the child with the function `reloadParentData:(id)sender`.

2) Have the parent controller `alloc` and `init` the child controller and set its delegate to be the parent (`self` on the parent).

3) Have the child controller call the `delegate`'s `reloadParentData:` function when needed.

4) Have the parent controller reload data (or possibly store `bool` indicating that data needs to be reloaded on `viewWillAppear:`) and possibly also dismiss/pop the child controller when it receives a call to `reloadParentData:` function

Comment: Hi, I'm new to objective-c and I'm lost to implement your tips. Would you write a code to demonstrate it?

Comment: I'm willing to write up some code to demonstrate this, but as I read your original question and the answers by JRG-Developer and rdelmar, I can't help but wonder if rdelmar's interpretation is the correct one. The code you've sketched out in your question seems to suggest so---so just to clarify: do you want to know how code in a method in MainViewController can call the reloadData method in ChildViewController? Or, do you want to know how code in the ChildViewController class can trigger a table reload or something similar in the MainViewController?